# Include a .jar with maven using eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, dependencies

I know this could be a duplicate of many questions, but i cannot really understand how does maven works.
Basically i want to include a dependency on my final project, but i cannot understand how.
For the moment; this is my pom.xml

```
 <dependency>
<groupId>bla.bla</groupId>
<artifactId>bla-bla-bla</artifactId>
<version>aVersion</version>
<scope>shade</scope>
</dependency>
```

(Not the original pom.xml, i just hided names)

But when i export it, open it with winrar i cannot see the dependency included in my .jar.
Anyone would be able to help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eclipse automatically export the jars from the maven repository.
you can manually build this project from command line
mvn clean install -U 
and check the logs whether the above jar is getting downloaded or not.

Comment: I did it, but i cannot find where the exported jar is

Comment: If that external jar is getting downloaded, you can find it in the WEB-INF folder of your war.